# Will rewriting my URLs into "Pretty URLs" cause any 404 errors?

Tags: php, web, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Good day! I have a question regarding removing file extensions from URLs.

If I were to use the following rule to remove the .php extension from my website URLs, would any prior links to any of the websites pages break?

Such as if www.site.com/archives.php became www.site.com/archives 
will any link that lead to www.site.com/archives.php still lead to www.site.com/archives or will it cause a 404?

The rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a redirection code.. when you call site.com/archives then is automatically called site.com/archives.php and the answer is no.. there is no problem in calling site.com/archives.php after applying this conditions

Comment: As @JanDvorak says, just test it. If you are in production phase, it's a good idea to have another page (or subdomain) where you try other new features.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you a better solution.

```
RewriteEngine on

# dont rewrite for directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And now you can use in the index.php the variable

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

you can read the file that was requested

example:

Url: http://my-site.de/Archives

then in the request var you will have the string "Archives" now you can parse the string with strtolower to lowercase (i would prefer this.. if the uri was called via camel case)

Another Example:

Url: http://my-site.de/Archives/Latest/Show

The Request Variable contains the string "Archives/Latest/Show"

Now you can use the directory to find the file on the server in the same directory or use the path as parameters for the request.

The Solution with the PHP ending would look like this in php:

```
<?php
$requestedPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (substr(strtolower($requestedPath),-4) != '.php') {
    $requestedPath .= '.php';
}

if (file_exists($requestedPath)) {
    include_once($requestedPath);
}
?>
```